# Sharepoint 2013 Designer workflow suspended

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

Workflow suspended:

> Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.InvalidOperationException: Looking up a value using a key is not supported on an instance of 'Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicJsonArray'. at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicItem.TryGetValue(String key, DynamicItem& value) at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.ObjectPathSegment.Get(DynamicItem obj) at Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager

I am not able to get the http call results to `d/results` I guess. Please help me in solving this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

It looks as though we were doing the same demo! I had the same steps and error. I managed to find this great [article on sharepoint dictionaries](http://plumsail.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-work-with-dictionaries-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-workflow/#BuildDictionaryManually) which helped explain it. You need to add brackets around the dictionary index when using the "Get an item from a dictionary" step.

```
([%Variable: index%])/Title
```

Comment: Your answer helped me, but I would edit it to clarify specifically what was wrong. We also followed the same tutorial, and the simple answer is that the tutorial already creates another dictionary based off of 'd/result'. The calls to that other dictionary when it comes to getting key values then in turn don't need 'd/result' to prefix the index number which is why the error was happening. Simply ([%Variable: index%])/Key is all that's needed then.

Comment: Perentheses are what is needed.  Brackets are added by SPD by default