# SharePoint Workflow 2013 always Suspended showing Looking up a value using a key is not supported

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow

I am having this issue in SP Workflow 2013 that every time it executed , it always goes to Suspended stage.

However, After completing the web service call and reading the d/results it shows the error

[image]

> RequestorId: 3d5f4981-27fc-e36f-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.InvalidOperationException: Looking up a value using a key is not supported on an instance of 'Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicPrimitive'. at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicItem.TryGetValue(String key, DynamicItem& value) at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.ObjectPathSegment.Get(DynamicItem obj) at Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Kindly assist

Cheers, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the path of "Get item from dictionary" is wrong.

Please refer below article to work with dictionaries in SharePoint 2013:

https://medium.com/plumsail/how-to-work-with-dictionaries-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-workflow-6956bd6bed9f#BuildDictionaryManually

Here are some similar issues for your reference:

[Sharepoint 2013 Designer workflow suspended](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128512/sharepoint-2013-designer-workflow-suspended)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a10c5e7e-cefc-47bb-9ec5-14abfd8dc922/call-http-web-service-workflow-action-access-json-data-in-dictionary?forum=sharepointdevelopment

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/55e836f2-e71d-4197-b8fe-91c0773a3421/how-to-get-json-item-in-web-service-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: Hi, Same workflow working in the Dev Environment. Having issue while publishing in production